# why my knative trigger status Unknown due to TopicReady Unknown?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing

Recently I'm trying out the Knative sample https://github.com/meteatamel/knative-tutorial/blob/master/docs/image-processing-pipeline.md, I have created knative trigger with default broker(MTChannelBasedBroker) & trigger, I have also installed the Google Cloud Pub/Sub Channel in the same namespace. I'm not sure what causes this error.
[image]

Comment: I can only see something that look like the output of a describe command. Could you specify what is the error and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I was trying to create a trigger for a GCP pub/sub resource (cloudstoragesource), but my trigger is in the unknown state, I think this happens due to authentication failure @CarlosS.

Answer (score 0):

This is being addressed in https://github.com/meteatamel/knative-tutorial/issues/84, please follow that issue for updates.